# Paging library returns empty list initially

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging

I'm using Paging library to paginate a list of items I'm retrieving from my server. Initially, when my fragment is loaded, it returns an empty list. But after changing fragments and going back to that fragment, I can see the list loaded. After debugging I saw that data was actually being fetched, but an empty list was passed to my fragment.

**ItemDataSource:**

```
@Override
public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<Integer, Item> callback) {
    apiService.getItems(OFFSET)
    .enqueue(new Callback<ItemWrapper>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ItemWrapper> call,@NonNull Response<ItemWrapper> response) {
            callback.onResult(response.body().getItems(), null, OFFSET + 25);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ItemWrapper> call,@NonNull Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, Item> callback) {

}

@Override
public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, Item> callback) {
    apiService.getItems(params.key)
            .enqueue(new Callback<ItemWrapper>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ItemWrapper> call,@NonNull Response<ItemWrapper> response) {
                    Integer key = response.body().getItems().isEmpty() ? null : params.key + 25;
                    callback.onResult(response.body().getItems(), key);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ItemWrapper> call,@NonNull Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

**ItemDataSourceFactory:**

```
@Override
public DataSource create() {
    ItemDataSource itemDataSource = new ItemDataSource();
    itemLiveDataSource.postValue(itemDataSource);
    return itemDataSource;
}

public MutableLiveData<ItemDataSource> getItemLiveDataSource() {
    return itemLiveDataSource;
}
```

**ItemViewModel:**

```
private LiveData<ItemDataSource> liveDataSource;
private LiveData<PagedList<Item>> itemPagedList;

private ItemViewModel(Application application) {
    ItemDataSourceFactory factory = new ItemDataSourceFactory();
    liveDataSource = factory.getItemLiveDataSource();

    PagedList.Config config = (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPageSize(ItemDataSource.LIMIT).build();

    itemPagedList = (new LivePagedListBuilder(factory, config)).build();
}

public LiveData<PagedList<Item>> getItems() {
    return itemPagedList;
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
ItemViewModel itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemViewModel.class);
itemViewModel.getItems.observe(this, items -> {
    adapter.submitList(items);
})
```

Comment: Could you add the code of adapter#submitList() please? Perhaps its just something trivial like not doing a notifyDataChanged. Also you should try debugging to see how far the data goes, since - as you wrote - it is fetched from the server.

Comment: @Ridcully I'm using the predefined `submitList()` method of PagedListAdapter. I didn't override it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Also, will be great if you can share what worked for you.

Comment: @ABS I rewrote this entire code from scratch and it started working. But I couldn't pinpoint exactly where was the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Not 100% sure, but I think this is because you are running an asynchronous request. try to change it to run synchronously for `loadInitial()` like so `request.execute()`

Comment: It's supposed to be an asynchronous request!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem once and I still can't figure it out why it does not work for some fragments. The solution I found, aldo being more like a fast sketchy fix is to load the fragment twice.

Answer (score 2):

Yassin Ajdi is right. `loadinitial()` calls immediately on the same thread where PagedList is created on. As your API is async, the method runs empty for the first time

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, anyone is using an asynchronous RxJava/Kotlin call in `loadInitial`. I finally figured out a solution after many painful hours.

I tried using a delayed Handler (500ms) in the `Observer` method but it was fickle and didn't work in every scenario. No matter how much I tried to make it synchronous using `setFetcher` and Rx `observeOn` it wouldn't consistently work.

My solution was to use `.blockingSubscribe` in my Observable. My data fetcher was using a Socket library that had its own concurrency out of my scope, so I couldn't guarantee that I could make the process wholly synchronous as Paging requires. (A process which needs better documentation IMO). Anyway, here's my solution, hopefully it helps others with same issue:

```
    override fun loadInitial(
            params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
            callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, ResultItem>
    ) {
       mySocketClientRxRequest()
                .subscribe ({
                    callback.onResult(it.resultItems 1, 2)
                },{
                    it.printStackTrace()
                })
    }
```

to

```
    override fun loadInitial(
            params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
            callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, ResultItem>
    ) {
       mySocketClientRxRequest()
                .blockingSubscribe ({
                    callback.onResult(it.resultItems 1, 2)
                },{
                    it.printStackTrace()
                })
    }
```

Comment: you're not canceling requests at all with this approach

Comment: @Kibotu you could also argue I shouldn't be using blocking rx call in production, but it is what it is, a workaround for a fundamental flaw in Paging 2 library.

Though out of interest, what kind of cancellation would you expect?

Comment: imagine you have a search where you have to invalidate on each letter, then you're not interested in most requests if the user types. sidenote: the blocking is ok since we're already on arcio thread by pagination library, bad part is that even with setting own executioner, the empty list part stays

Answer (score 0):

Just as in the question I was loading the data asynchronously inside loadInitial, but the data did not come to the adapter when callback was called.

Solved just by updating the library version from
`androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.2`
to `androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem as well for a few days until finally I found the solution. But just to note I used Paging version 3, so this might not answer this question directly, but might help anyone who's still struggling in blank recyclerView initially

In your fragment where you applied `PagingAdapter`, use `loadStateFlow` on the adapter to observe changes in `loadState`. You can place this in `onCreateView` for Fragment

```
val pagingAdapter = PagingAdapter()
lifecycleScope.launch {
        pagingAdapter.loadStateFlow.collect { loadState ->
            if (loadState.prepend.endOfPaginationReached) {
             // Apply this if PagingDataAdapter start binding data in view holder
                println("APPLYING ADAPTER")
                binding.recyclerView.adapter = pagingAdapter
                cancel() // Cancel this flow after applying adapter
            }
        }
    }
```